# Registering to an event raised by jquery in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I java a jquery part on my page that triggers certain custom events.
 another part of my page is an angular app. I have tried in a controller of the angular app to register to a jquery event : the jquery code does :

```
$("body").trigger("customEvent",data);
```

and the angular registered to it in the controller  like so:

```
$("body").on('customEvent',function(event,data) {alert("here"); });
```

but in the normal flow I don't get the event. a weird thing is that when I try to do in the console the same $("body").trigger... the angular handler is called. 
Anyone has an idea how to make this work? unfortunately I can't change the jquery part to angular, or the other way around.

Comment: Where is AngularJS here..?

Comment: The $("body").on part is written inside an angular controller

Comment: If you are using angular than why using jquery for triggering event. Angular directives are there.  I will suggest you make a directive for this. And as you have posted small code, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: As i said, the angular app is in a completely different part of the page and code. I can't trigger the event from inside the angular code.. Can i register it in a directive? How?

Answer (score 0):

I think body is triggering event before angular code is ready. One probable solution is call your trigger event code in timeout as shown below:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("body").trigger("customEvent",data); 
}, 500);
```

I think this should solve your problem.